# Override default profile view with profile2's profile fields

Tags: users

I have made 2 profile 'A' and 'B' with profile2. Profiles are searchable by all users including 'anonymous' user type.

A user search for user named 'a' then search result appears. When I click on that result, it shows default user profile view (Only History: Member for) not the profile2 fields associated with user 'a'.

As I want to show profile2 field in search not the just default one. Please help in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought Profile2 had an option to override that.

Maybe you could use [Global Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) or [Path Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect) to redirect users visiting the account page to the profile page.

Another option could be creating a view for the searches, and then adding the user/profile relationship.